Pushforward of structure sheaf with respect to canonical inclusion of Grassmannian
Let $j: Gr^{k,n} \rightarrow Gr^{k,n+1}$ be the canonical inclusion of Grassmannians (working over a field for simplicity). I am interested the pushforward $j_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Gr^{k,n}}$. Specifically, I would like to know whether this pushforward can be computed in some sense.
Thoughts so far:
As $j$ is a closed immersion, it follows that $j_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Gr^{k,n}} \cong \mathcal{O}_{Gr^{k,n+1}} / \mathcal{J}$, where $\mathcal{J}$ is the sheaf of ideals associated with closed immersion $j$.
But my feeling is that $\mathcal{J}$ is no easier to compute, so I get stuck.
Any thoughts/references would be much appreciated!

What do you mean by canonical embedding? I don’t know how to do this but can it not be worked out using, say, affine coordinates?

Yes, $\mathrm{Gr}(k,n) \subset \mathrm{Gr}(k,n+1)$ is the zero locus of a regular global section of the dual tautological bundle $\mathcal{U}^\vee$, therefore there is a Koszul resolution
$$
0 \to \wedge^k\mathcal{U} \to \dots \to \wedge^2\mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{U} \to \mathcal{I} \to 0,
$$
where $\mathcal{I}$ is the corresponding ideal sheaf.

Awesome! Thank you so much.
